# Serialization issue with Spark and ObjectMapper in Spring Boot-based applicatuon

Tags: java, spring, apache-spark, jackson, objectmapper

I'm using Spark and there's one of my Spring Boot-based application beans:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeService implements FlatMapFunction<T, K> {

  private final ObjectMapper mapper;
  
}
```

`ObjectMapper` here is the standard one taken from application context. The problem is that the app fails with `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`. Here's serialization stack:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.http.converter.json.SpringHandlerInstantiator
Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: org.springframework.http.converter.json.SpringHandlerInstantiator, value: org.springframework.http.converter.json.SpringHandlerInstantiator@6e4912db)
- field (class: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.BaseSettings, name: _handlerInstantiator, type: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.HandlerInstantiator)
- object (class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.BaseSettings, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.BaseSettings@155616d8)
- field (class: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig, name: _base, type: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.BaseSettings)
- object (class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig@66e72ca2)
- field (class: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper, name: _deserializationConfig, type: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig)
- object (class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper@433ef204)
- field (class: com.smth.SomeService, name: mapper, type: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper)
```

So the problem is about non-serializable `SpringHandlerInstantiator`.

This far I work this around by assigning `mapper` field in constructor manually:

```java
public SomeService() {
  this.mapper = new ObjectMapper();
}
```

Is there a way to somehow solve this properly, i. e. relying on Spring's DI?

I use Spring Boot 2.6.7 and Spark 2.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to configure ObjectMapper bean to use a serializable HandlerInstantiator. In the following example `MyHandlerInstantiator` is a custom implementation of `HandlerInstantiator` which is serializable (e.g. it can be started with minimal patching the code of `SpringHandlerInstantiator`). This should allow SomeService class to be serializable as well and compatible for usage in a distributed environment like Apache Spark.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
  
  @Bean
  public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setHandlerInstantiator(new MyHandlerInstantiator());
    return mapper;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already solved the issue in exactly the way you suggested.